# Character Tables of large groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, characters

I need to export LaTex files of character tables of various groups to write a project report. I usually use this site:

[https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/index.html)

However they do not have character tables for large groups as the Suzuki Group Sz(8) or Mathieu sporadic groups. Is there any other good website with character tables of larger groups? Alternatively, can someone suggest book containing character table of $M_{22}, M_{23}, M_{24}$ and $Sz(8)$?

Comment: Do you actually want a charater table for so large groups ?

Comment: Yes, the number of conjugacy classes is $11$ for $Sz(8)$ and $12$ for $M_{22}$ so at least for these groups it should be possible to find them somewhere.

Comment: The tables are stored in GAP and can be printed with PrintCharacterTable.

Comment: On second thought, "Display" gives a nicer output than "PrintCharacterTable". To obtain LaTeX code, one could write an easy procedure, but converting the irrationalities can be tedious.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I still have one question regarding this. In the webpage that I referred to previously, columns are ordered by order of the elements of the conjugacy class, but this is not the case in GAP. Does anyone know what criterion they follow?

Comment: If you get the character tabkes in GAP from the table library (i.e. `CharacterTable("M22");` the classes will be ordered as in the ATLAS.